Is Parallel Task Necessary in Async Context Manager for Managing Connections in Python?
I'm working on a Python project where I'm managing connections to a heating system. I have a class ControllableHeatingSystemStore that inherits from HeatingSystemStore. In this class, I have an async context manager open_connection that opens a connection, starts a background task to acquire control of the heating system, and then cancels the task when the connection is closed.
Here's the relevant code:
class ControllableHeatingSystemStore(
    HeatingSystemStore[HubControlConnection, ControllableHeatingSystem]
):
    @asynccontextmanager
    async def open_connection(
        self, connection: HubControlConnection, building_id: str
    ) -> AsyncGenerator[HubControlConnection, None]:
        async with super().open_connection(connection, building_id) as conn:

            async def await_acquire_control() -> None:
                await conn.acquire_control()
                self.add_heating_system(
                    building_id, CloudControllableHeatingSystem(conn)
                )

            async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
                t = tg.create_task(await_acquire_control())
                yield conn
                t.cancel()

I'm using this pattern quite frequently throughout the codebase and I'm wondering if I'm overcomplicating things. I know I could easily wrap this pattern into a utility context manager (e.g. async with BackgroundTask(await_acquire_control())). But could this all be handled with a single task? Could there be a more efficient or Pythonic way to manage these connections without tying the lifecycle of the background task to the context manager? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
